# Shipping code showing in Paypal Express Account in Magento2

Tags: magento2, paypal-express

I want to show **only shipping title not shipping code** in Paypal express checkout in Magento2.
[image]

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Yes I solved it now! see screen shot in my answer shipping code not showing

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the shipping options from showing up in Paypal Express by doing some settings in the Magento Admin:

> Go to Paypal Express Checkout Advance Setting

[image]

Set `Transfer Shipping Options` to **No**

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I want transfer shipping option with name and price but without shipping code?

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> /vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php
>
> line no. 984

and comment  **`'code' => $rate->getCode(),`**

```
$options[$i] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
[
 'is_default' => $isDefault,
 'name' => trim("{$rate->getCarrierTitle()} - {$rate->getMethodTitle()}", ' -'),
 /*'code' => $rate->getCode(),*/
 'amount' => $amountExclTax,
]
);
```

[image]